# Three apps one namespace

Tags: python, django, django-urls

What I am trying to do is to have common namespace for two or more apps.

Lets say I have an apps folder with 3 apps in it: dashboard (admin panel to display other apps), clients (displays fancy tables), and orders (same as clients).
Looks like this:

```
--  apps
    |-- dashboard
    |   |-- views.py
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- urls.py
    |-- clients
    |   |-- views.py
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- urls.py
    |-- orders
    |   |-- views.py
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- urls.py
```

In my main urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^dashboard/', include('apps.dashboard.urls',
                                namespace='dashboard',
                                app_name='dashboard')),
```

In dashboard/urls.py:

```
url(r'^clients/', include('apps.clients.urls')),
url(r'^orders/', include('apps.orders.urls')),
```

And in clients:

```
url(r'^$', views.AllClientsList.as_view(), name='clients-all'),
```

So, I'd like to have the same namespace for urls in clients and orders app, to use them as `{% url "dashboard:clients-all" %}`. But it simply doesn't work - `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'customers_detailed' not found. 'customers_detailed' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Is there any way to do it?

Update: 
Links like `<a href='{% url 'dashboard:customers-all' %}'>Customers</a>` throw erroes "Reverse for 'customers-all' not found. 'customers-all' is not a valid view function or pattern name." 
urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [ url(r'^dashboard/', include('apps.dashboard.urls')), ]
```

apps/dashboard/urls.py

```
 app_name = 'dashboard'
 urlpatterns = [ url(r'^customers/', include('apps.customers.urls')), ]
```

apps/customers/urls.py

```
 app_name = 'customers'
 urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', views.AllCustomerList.as_view(), name='customers-all'), ]
```

Comment: You haven't shown either the view/template where you are trying to reverse `'customers_detailed` or the url pattern in question.

Comment: @Alasdair Django crashes at `<a href='{% url "dashboard:clients-all" %}'>All Clients</a>` (should be /dashboard/clients/). Or should I show you the whole template?

Comment: If it crashes there, then I wouldn't expect the error message to contain `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'customers_detailed'`.

Comment: Please don't post error messages or code in the comments, they are difficult to read - [edit] your question instead.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok, updated the post

Comment: Your customers URLs also contains a namespace. Try `{% url 'dashboard:customers:customers-all' %}`. As an aside, you shouldn't need to use `app_name` in the `include()` since you have set in in the `urls.py`. You shouldn't need `namespace` either unless you are going to include the app multiple times.

Comment: @Alasdair That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `dashboard` urls includes the `customers` urls, you need to include the nested namespace:

```
{% url 'dashboard:customers:customers-all' %}
```